# Selfhosted Asp.Net Core WebAPi with http.sys webserver deploy

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, http.sys

I'm trying to deploy selfhosted Asp.Net Core WebApi. I replaced the default Kestrel web server with Http.sys. I'm deploying on a virtual machine with Windows Server 2016. 
When I request the api locally (from the virtual machine) I can access it without any problems on http://localhost:61152.
The problem is that I can't access it from the host machine.
I opened the port 61152 in the Windows Firewall.
In the program.cs I have:

```
.UseStartup<Startup>().UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            options.MaxConnections = null;
            options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
            options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:61152/");

        }).Build();
```

I use asp.net core 2.0. I browse with the IP of the server which like this:
http://192.168.0.112:61152/

Also I have IIS running on the guest machine and I can see the default IIS page.

Can you please tell what I'm doing wrong or direct me to an article how to fix this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I just changed the http://localhost:61152/ to http://*:61152/